# Service Applications not installing to correct server

Tags: service-application, provisioning, visio-services

I have set up a 2016 farm with 2xWFE, 2xAPP, 1xSQL.

I'm trying to install and provision service applications specifically to APP1, but am having trouble. The "Visio Graphics Service" application only seems to provision on WFE1. I have successfully stopped the service on WFE1, but there is no option to start it on APP1. Have blown away the whole application and tried again with no success.

Does this have something to do with specifying "Roles" for servers during installation? I feel like I'm missing something very basic here that I didn't encounter in 2010 and 2013!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does have to do with MinRoles, and yes the FE is the correct place for VSG as it is a service application that services interactive content for end users; placing it on the back end ("app") servers would slow down end user requests.